# NEXT JS: gtServerSideProps devuelve null

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

tengo este componente en el cual quiero cargar la info de una API, estuve leyendo la documentación de NextJS, pero cuando le hago **console.log** a posts me devuelve **undefined**

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#simple-example-1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

componente

```
export default function PostsHome( { posts } ) {

    console.log(posts);

    return (
        
      <>
         Noticias
      </>

    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');    
    const posts = await resp.json();


    return {
        props: {
            posts
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Según la documentación que has aportado, te faltaría el `export default PostsHome`.

Comment: Ya lo estoy exportando con el export default function PostsHome, ese componente lo estoy importando en el index.js y se muestra el texto que dice Noticias

Comment: ¿Has pensado que pueda ser que no puedas hacer un return de props.posts porque tienen el mismo nombre que el parámetro de la función?